# SyntaxHighlighter is null

Tags: javascript, syntaxhighlighter

I am using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html).  I followed the installation steps and I'm receiving a few errors in the firebug console:

> TypeError: SyntaxHighlighter is null
>
> ReferenceError: XRegExp is not defined

I imported the necessary files.

**Markup**

[image]

Why I am getting these errors?

Comment: Sounds like you need to put your XRegExp.js reference before the shCore.js reference. But, really, it's hard to tell without more detail.

Comment: @mafafu - Yes that answered it.  I moved the import of XRegExp.js above ShCore.js and it works now. I was under the impression that the order of imports does not matter in javascript.  Can you explain why this resolved the problem?

Comment: Order does matter when there's a dependency. One of the most common examples being that you have to load jQuery before you can use jQueryUI.

Comment: @mafafu - ok.  Well you answered the question so if u want to post these as an answer I will give you answer credit.  Thanks!

Comment: Alright, glad I could help. I combined the two comments for the answer, in case it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to put your XRegExp.js reference before the shCore.js reference. Order does matter when there's a dependency. One of the most common examples being that you have to load jQuery before you can use jQueryUI.